# For dentro de un método

Tags: java, bucle-for

Tengo que recibir el nombre y puntaje de una serie de luchadores, y retornar quién haya tenido el mayor puntaje. Esto es un for dentro de un método. Pidiendo los datos del main. Pero no me está funcionando el ciclo. No está terminado pero el ciclo debería de funcionar.

```
        iniciar();
    opcion = in.readLine().charAt(0);
    switch(opcion) {
        case 'A':
        out.print("Por favor digite cuántos peleadores va a ingresar: ");
        numPeleadores = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            out.print("Por favor digite el nombre del peleador: ");
            nombrePeleador = in.readLine();
            out.print("Por favor digite cuántos puntos tiene en el ranking: ");
            puntos = Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
            mejorPeleador = mejorRank(numPeleadores, nombrePeleador, puntos);

        out.print("El peleador mejor rankeado es: "+mejorPeleador);
        break;
        case 'B':
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
}
static String mejorRank (int pNumPeleadores, String pNombrePeleador, double pPuntos) {
    double entregaMayor =-1;
    String nombreMejor="";
    int i;
    for (i =1; i <=pNumPeleadores; i++) {  
    }
    if (pPuntos > entregaMayor) {
        entregaMayor = pPuntos;
        nombreMejor = pNombrePeleador;
    } 
    return nombreMejor; 
}
```

Comment: Tu código tiene varios detalles 1- `for (i =1; i <=pNumPeleadores; i++) {  
    }` el for no ejecuta ninguna sentencia.. 2- Debes tener un `for` para leer los datos del **pNumPeleadores** como lo tienes solo lees los datos de 1 solo peleador

Comment: Además tu código no compila, trata siempre de poner un [mcve]

Comment: Si he entendido bien lo que quieres hacer, la función mejor rank debería recibir como parametro una lista de peleadores y devolver el que tenga la mejor puntuación. Sin embargo en el switch ni siquiera puedes leer los datos de más de un luchador, supongo que esa identación es para un bucle (que itere un numero de veces igual al pedido por consola justo antes) que vaya pidiendo uno a uno los datos de los peleadores. Despues de tener todos los datos podrias llamar a la función mejorRank.